# Python - reading from CSV - ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I am getting started using Python and Anaconda. I am trying to create a lineplot, similar to what I was able to generate successfully using R. When I try the code below to try to read in a csv file, I get the error `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

```
import csv
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter="\t")
    return [result[column] for result in results if len(result) > column]

Season = getColumn("vs.csv",0)
VORP = getColumn("vs.csv",2)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure("VORP vs Season")
plt.xlabel("Season")
plt.ylabel("VORP")
plt.legend(["PlayerA","PlayerB"], loc=9,ncol=2)
plt.plot(Season, VORP)
plt.show()
```

The CSV file simply contain entries as below:

```
Season  Player   VORP
'0405'  PlayerA  .7
'0506'  PlayerA  .14
[and so on]
'0405'  PlayerB  .23
'0506'  PlayerB  -.3
[and so on]
```

Comment: And in one of the lines it does not.

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter is `\t`?  What you've shown looks to be delimited by some number of spaces.

Comment: You might try: `results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)`  But how you want to get from two lists of strings (what `Season` and `VORP` will be) to a plot isn't clear.

Comment: When I open that csv file in Excel, they are in seperate columns, so thats why I set `delimiter="\t"`. If I try `delimiter=" "`, I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data analysis library that comes with Anaconda. It is supposed to provide some of the same functionality as R, so it may be a good option for you. And it greatly simplifies importing and manipulating data from csv files. It also has nice [plotting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html) capabilities, which use [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/).

First, import `pandas` and `matplotlib.pyplot`, and use the former to create a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) object from your csv. If you print the DataFrame to the console, you can see it looks quite nice and pretty.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('vorp.csv', index_col=None)
>>> print df

   Season   Player  VORP
0  '0405'  PlayerA  0.70
1  '0506'  PlayerA  0.14
2  '0405'  PlayerB  0.23
3  '0506'  PlayerB -0.30
```

Now call the [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) method on your DataFrame. This will just return another DataFrame object, but it will be organised a way that makes it simple to graph. You will want to set 'VORP' as the values, 'Season' as the index (i.e. rows), and 'Player' as the columns, like so:

```
>>> table = df.pivot_table('VORP', 'Season', 'Player')
>>> print table

Player  PlayerA  PlayerB
Season                  
'0405'     0.70     0.23
'0506'     0.14    -0.30
```

Now it's just a matter of plotting the table. Just call the [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method on your pivot table (which will return a [`matplotlib.axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) object), and use `matplotlib` to manipulate it however you like. I've added the y-axis label and a title, for example.

```
>>> ax = table.plot()
>>> ax.set_title('VORP vs Season')
>>> ax.set_ylabel('VORP')
>>> plt.show()
```

And here is the result, which will no doubt look nicer with your full dataset.
[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, that makes alot more sense